# Did banning LMGTFY links ultimately lead to quick downvote on simple/effortless questions?

Tags: feature-request, flags, close-reasons, comments

Now I just ran into 2-3 Meta SO questions which, in the long run, discussed elitism and eager downvoting/flags on SO, which ultimately lead me to wonder why people aren't posting LMGTFY links. After a quick google search revealed that it was purposely banned.

I remember when I used to ask a friend of mine questions, when I swapped to C#, I'd ask awfully simple questions too, resulting in him sending me a LMGTFY link, which in the end merely pointed out to me how painfully easy and timesaving it would have been just to look for the info myself.

Seeing how LMGTFY is banned and most people flag/downvote without a comment by now, I was wondering on whether it would make sense to create an additional flag to split up "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful" into two seperate points and maybe reword it a little.

- "This question does not show any research effort, is trivial and could be solved by yourself with minor effort"
- "It is unclear or not useful" ( This one might deserve a rewording too. I've run into quite a bunch of questions where people didn't know how to complete their business requirements instead of technical requirements. Having problems with technical requirements is generic enough to be viable for SO in my opinion)

Seeing how you can't post LMGTFY links, I think it would make sense to have a flag to tell people that the reason their question was flagged pretty much is "If you you can't be bothered to spend 5 minutes on google you don't deserve 5 minutes (times 30~people) of other people".

**Am I alone with this thought of going a way between LMGTFY and commentless downvote/flag?**

Comment: i don't see anything wrong with commentless downvoting. Maybe the downvote tooltip should be more visible to askers after the question receives x downovtes.

Comment: What does "LMGTFY" mean?

Comment: "let me google that for you" there's a website that animates googling a search term and then redirects to google.

Comment: @KevinB They may accidentally think that the reason may be that they were "unclear". I would prefer it was straight pointed out to them that the reason for flag was solely that it shows no effort.

Comment: just to be clear, you mean *research* effort, right?

Comment: @KevinB Yes, of course. It doesn't have to be googling really. It's annoying when someone asks questions and it's obvious, that they haven't even looked for viable intellisense suggestions when working with a class.

Comment: @JohnnyBones http://lmgtfy.com/?q=lmgtfy

Comment: @AndreasMüller Except people *did* provide reasons for downvoting...

Comment: @Servy I'm pretty sure putting "lmgtfy" into lmgtfy causes the universe to collapse on itself.

Comment: @Servy Not really - Disagreeing with someones opinion without any argument is no reason to downvote. Other than that i don't see anyone but Bill the Lizard actually taking a constructive stand to this yet.

Comment: @AndreasMüller "Disagreeing with someones opinion without any argument is no reason to downvote."  Except that it is...  And on top of that when you claim to be receiving downvotes without a reason, and then later on talk about the person taking a constructive stance against your proposal you contradict yourself.

Comment: That and down votes here precisely mean disagreement.

Comment: @Servy It's not contradicting that. A well built opinion about a topic is based on actually having reasons for your opinion and beeing able to express them. If someone voices an argument contradicting me i have no problem with that whatsoever. If someone pretty much just says "no" and can't explain why all i am thinking is "wow, a child could have come up with that tactic of participating in a discussion and voicing his opinion with zero material for an argument"

Comment: @KevinB In a matter of "one click says more than a dozen words", like any person who is capable of expressing his opinion would do, right?

Comment: My point was down votes on meta are different.

Comment: @KevinB Yeah that's true obviously. However it still stands true that the information value of just a simple downvote is pretty small. Imagine you have a discussion with a colleague and you say "i love linq" and he says "i think it sucks" and he can't come up with a reason. I'm pretty sure you'd think he's an idiot then since he obviously can't express why he thinks that way and there is no way to tell wether he might actually be right about it since he provides no information on his reasoning

Comment: You tell a nice story of learning from your friend's use of lmgtfy. That's nice, but it requires you to recognize that your friend is acting with good will, to have a level of self reflection consistent with spotting your own failure in the scenario, and to have sufficient self respect to shrug off the possibility that you have been insulted. That set of requirements are not met by all posters here, and lmgtfy-comments were causing a lot of angst and ill-feeling. And yeah, downvotes and closes *also* cause angst and ill-feelings, but it's generally less personal.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why does he have to defend his hating of it, but you don't have to defend your love of it?  Seems like a double standard to me.

Comment: @dmckee interesting point of view. for me commentless downvoting causes more ill-feeling than lmgtfy links. not everyone might feel that way of course. for me it's a sign that my question may have been painfully trivial to answer. However i am not interested in who's right, but rather what's right - which may be the reason for that attitude.

Comment: necrocomment but the comments on http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15650/ban-lmgtfy-let-me-google-that-for-you-links seem to agree with me by a 6:1 ratio. oh well

Answer (score 9):

You're proposing a flag that says:

> If you you can't be bothered to spend 5 minutes on google you don't deserve 5 minutes (times 30~people) of other people.

Compare that to:

> This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful.

The latter message is exactly what you're saying when you downvote a question. (It's the hover text of the downvote button.) In essence, *we already have* a flag that tells people that they should have Googled their problem before posting it on Stack Overflow. There's no need to post a snarky LMGTFY link along with that message. If you want to leave a *polite* comment along with (or instead of) your downvote, there's nothing stopping you.

Comment: I know. My point is differentiating between no research effort and unclear/not useful instead of leaving it to be just one common flag.

Comment: @AndreasMüller As I mentioned, there's nothing stopping you from telling people why you downvoted. You're just not allowed to use LMGTFY to do it. That's not the only way to communicate that a question is easily Google-able.

Comment: @AndreasMüller [For example](https://www.google.com/search?q=How+do+I+indicate+that+a+question+is+easily+googable+without+using+LMGTFY)

Comment: @BilltheLizard I would agree with you on that usually but what i'm seeing is that people are escalating their temper when they run into the 20th duplicate that day for questions they've flagged 5 times already and don't just leave it at "You can google that". Reducing expression of that option down to a flag expressing just that, could take out the temper of what they are trying to advice. Because i don't really want to flag the person who gets pissed off by it either, because i can relate. Then again i guess it doesn't matter with all the downvotes this question gets