# What exactly is considered 'Rude or Offensive' in comments anymore?

Tags: discussion, support, flags, comment-flags, rude-or-abusive

I know all too well the routine of a new Stack Overflow user. They ask a poor question, and then get burned by comments saying things such as:

- "Go do your own homework"
- "Have you tried anything?"
- "Have you even tried to solve your problem?"
- "Nobody is going to do your homework for you. Go do it yourself"
- "Did you try Google?"

This is the majority of the comments I've seen on new users' posts. In my opinion, all of the above comments are rude, and should be flagged accordingly. However when I've done so once or twice, I've had my flag rejected. I've also seen people quickly upvote comments that are similar to the above.

What's going on here? What happened to the be nice policy? Yes I know that bad questions are posted hundreds of times a day, and that it can be tiring and annoying explaining to the new user that their question is a bad fit for Stack Overflow. But why even spend the time making a rude comment like that, telling the user what they did wrong. Just flag, vote to close, or downvote the question and go on if you don't want to explain.

Comment: Well there you go, you're defining the 21st century all over again. "Not constructive" is also an option, not everything is rude and offensive!

Comment: [Did you try google?](https://www.google.com/search?q=site:meta.stackoverflow.com+What+exactly+is+considered+'Rude+or+Offensive'+in+comments?)

Comment: duplicate of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184783/at-what-point-are-comments-classified-as-rude-or-offensive-for-off-topic-questio  (on metastackexchange, so cannot be a duplicate, but still). I just googled your question subject.

Comment: *"Have you tried anything?"* is not rude, it's asking a very good question. I don't know how many times I've answered a question only to have the OP comment on it, saying "I already tried that". Well, how am I supposed to know?

Comment: Does "please post your code, we cannot guess" count ?

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan See [“What have you tried” epidemic](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/172758/310998) on Meta Stack Exchange.

Comment: "Nobody is going to do your homework for you" is a civic behaviour to avoid that students get their diploma without working :) a bit agressive I admit, but if we cannot laugh a bit to the expense of newbies where's the fun? And "did you try google" is a way to avoid answering the question just in order to "farm rep" just using google.

Comment: @Gothdo Oh yeah, I remember that, which is why it's morphed into "Have you tried anything?", because the question still needs to be asked, and answered.

Comment: Mr.goosberry, sadly, this is a real problem you're raising, but too much people here think the blame is on the person asking the question, not the commentor, and that this would somehow justify the condescending attitude of the comments. This has been discussed before, and if that makes you feel any better, [those comments would be deleted if flagged as 'not constructive'](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/333403/1743880).

Comment: @Mr.goosberry All samples you listed could be at best considered _"not constructive"_, there's not a single bit of rudeness to be seen in any of them.

Comment: @Mr.goosberry _"it can be tiring and annoying explaining to the new user that their question is a bad fit for Stack Overflow"_ If you think its worth it you may use a [stock comment](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/insert-snippet/nfhllbdppejecjnhnjjagjhpcbjhkcpf?utm_source=chrome-app-launcher-info-dialog) to do so.

Comment: Asking what someone has tried is NOT rude.  Do you know what is rude?  Asking for help, then spending the next hour telling people "oh, I already did that."  It **wastes the time of people who are volunteering, for free, to help you**.

Comment: @Will no, asking what someone tried is perfectly fine. I do it all the time! But asking them with  conceding attitude **is not fine**. That is the point I'm raising.

Comment: I believe the word you are looking for is ["condescending"](https://www.google.ca/search?q=define+condescending). I don't believe that a ["conceding"](https://www.google.ca/search?q=define+conceding) attitude is "not fine". Admitting that something is true or valid after first denying or resisting it seems constructive enough to me.

Comment: @TinyGiant yep. Hands got ahead of the brain their ;). Thanks for point that out.

Comment: Who defines what is and is not *condescending*, that can be very subjective and you can be extremely *polite* while doing it which is mostly ignored here because it is *"polite"*. Personally I find the passive-aggressive comments and the declined flags they get more troubling, but that will be a question of my on here eventually.

Comment: I believe the word you are looking for is ["there"](https://www.google.ca/search?q=define+there).

Comment: @TinyGiant ahh!!!! Stop doing that!!!

Comment: I believe the word... </joking>

Answer (score 33, accepted):

None of those comments rises to the level of rudeness that warrants flagging as "rude or abusive." Asking people what they've tried when they've failed to show it is acceptable. There is a list of guidelines to follow for the "rude" flag on the [Be nice](https://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice) page:

> - **Name-calling**. Focus on the post, not the person. That includes terms that feel personal even when they're applied to posts (like "lazy", "ignorant", or "whiny").
> - **Bigotry of any kind**. Language likely to offend or alienate individuals or groups based on race, gender, sexual orientation, religion, etc. will not be tolerated. At all. (Those are just a few examples; when in doubt, just don't.)
> - **Inappropriate language or attention**. Avoid vulgar terms and anything sexually suggestive. Also, this is not a dating site.
> - **Harassment and bullying**. If you see a hostile interaction, flag it. If it keeps up, disengage — we'll handle it. If something needs staff attention, you can use the contact us link at the bottom of every page.

Asking people to show what they've tried falls well short of these guidelines, so please don't waste moderators' time by flagging innocuous comments as "rude or abusive." Those flags are treated with *very* high priority by moderators, so they should be used only when it's really warranted.

Comment: What about "not constructive"?

Comment: That ^^ or too chatty, let's keep SO clean

Comment: @TravisJ: The question was whether they are "considered rude or offensive". The answer is no, they are not. Whether they are considered "not constructive" was not the question being asked.

Comment: @TravisJ I think that depends on the question. Much of the time these comments are constructive.

Comment: context is everything

Comment: @NicolBolas - It is strongly related, and simply brushing the point aside because that isn't the exact text of the question sets a poor standard.

Comment: @BilltheLizard excluding "Did you try Google?" I instead would say that all those comment should be [deleted](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/333403/5292302), the appropriate flag probably is non-constructive. I know we are far from the [Summer of love](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/07/the-hunting-of-the-snark/) but I can't see any reason to encourage them

Comment: @PetterFriberg Really, you can't see any reason to leave comments like that? How about thousands of questions like [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/39604811/1288) every day?

Comment: @BilltheLizard just downvote and close vote, why do we like to create more noise?, frustration should not rule.

Comment: It boggles my mind that every day someone comes here to complain that they got downvoted without anyone explaining why, but people still want to actively delete those comments that explain why. Go ahead and flag those comments if the question is already closed or fixed, but until one of those things happens, they're feedback, leave them alone.

Comment: It bug's me even more that I see tons of those comments (often multiple on same post and angry op response, 20 lines of non constructive comment thread), but not a single close vote!. Result: I need to close vote, raise moderator flag to clean up mess, moderators need to clean up mess. But ok if we like to go this way, I try to continue shoveling all this crap

Comment: @PetterFriberg Bad questions are the real mess that need to be cleaned up. Comments on bad questions are just a side effect. I'm fine with cleaning them up, but at least wait until they've served their purpose.

Comment: meeh pi**ing on crap does not really make it more easy to clean up, it just gets messy.

Answer (score 6):

You seem to have two general classes of comments here:

> "Have you tried anything?"
>
> "Have you even tried to solve your problem?"
>
> "Did you try Google?"

I think these are fair questions. On Stack Overflow, you are expected to do your own research before asking. If your question does not show this research, this is a fair question.

> "Go do your own homework"
>
> "Nobody is going to do your homework for you. Go do it yourself"

These are also rather true. It's fine to ask questions about your homework, but posting your entire homework assignment as a question is not alright. Such a "question" is way too broad.

I wouldn't really call either any more rude than posting a question without the minimal requirements to be a good question. If we are going to start flagging short-and-to-the-point comments as rude, we might as well start holding short-and-vague questions to at least the same standards (questions are 1st-class citizens, and comments are only 2nd-class).

Comment: This answer is just defending the right to leave those kind of comments (that arguably are not strictly 'rude' as per [the site's definition](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/334872/1743880)) because *posting your entire homework assignment as a question is not alright*. While the quality of the post may be certainly bad, it is not an excuse to vent off, i.e. rudeness was never solved by rudeness in return. The help center and the close banner would convey the same intention, but in a lot more constructive way. So why not just vote to close and / or downvote, move on and be done with it?

Comment: @Tunaki Respectfully, the purpose of this answer is to show the comments are not actually rude, so there is no rudeness to defend. Sure, better comments are better, I'm doubtful many will invest the time though.

Comment: @Mr.goosberry - if you think they are *rude* because of they *way their being asked*, it is **the way you are interpreting them personally**, they might be offensive to you **personally**, why is only known to you in that case. But that does not make them universally offensive. Remember *your experience is not universal* goes both ways.

Comment: @Mr.goosberry I've asked programmers if they tried Google it to their face. Even in person, knowing what research someone has done on the topic helps me help them. Also, the analogy isn't great IMO, I would equate such a request to asking for directions to off-site resources, which are explicitly off-topic. I think a better analogy might be asking how to make a latte or something similar, where knowing what coffee making skills the asker already has would be helpful.

Comment: That straw man argument is just that. But to answer it, yes I would look at them and if they had a mobile phone in their hand and had an arrogant selfish entitlement attitude, I would most likely respond "Is your phone dead?" or the more southern version would be "Do you have a bone in your hand?" , if it was not I would turn and walk off. Those of use that use our real names are not *hiding behind the anonymity of a computer screen*, it is completely the opposite.

Answer (score 1):

You should think carefully about why your flag was rejected. It was rejected because you are wrong in your judgment.

I completely fail to see how recommending a Google search is rude. Is it the concept of recommending the search, or the particular blunt phrasing that offends you? Would this have been better?

> I wonder if I might humbly suggest that, on the off-chance that you have not already done so, you might try to search just a little bit harder for an answer to your question, such as by using Google?

Brusqueness, bluntness, and abrasiveness are to a large extent in the eye of the beholder. For every person that interprets "Did you try Google?" as hostile or rude, someone else will interpret as just meaning, well, "Did you try Google?".

If you're seriously concerned about this, then I suggest you make a specific feature request here on Meta for changes to the wording of the "nice" page.

The world is a brusque place. We encounter brusqueness on a daily basis. We're big boys and girls, and we learn to deal with it. Often brusqueness is useful, first because it shortens the message, and second because it conveys a bit of emphasis which, frankly, is what some people need.

Someone who is inclined to be personally insulted by either innocuous comments which they contort into criticism, or by comments which are in fact a bit on the brusque side, is not going to do too well here on SO, or on other forums/sites, or in the world at large for that matter. If brusque answers or comments do chase them away, I for one would shed no tears.

Comment: Yet, [LMGTFY links](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255397) [are](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262502) [banned](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/299281) (and described as "rude", "snarky", and "condescending"). What is the difference?

Comment: @PeterMortensen you can just post a link to the google search directly, if you add LMGTFY in between that's just superfluous. And funny.

Comment: @Gimby Well, it may be funny to you but the fact is that the side banned it, which is not really something to take lightly. Do you consider circumventing the restriction a good way to express oneself?

Comment: Actually, LMGTFY **drives traffic away** from here [Occam's Razor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Occam%27s_razor) suggests , that is more likely the reason they banned them and used the *rude* as the justification. I don't disagree with the ban on LMGTFY, the entire site exists to be sarcastic, but I don't agree that it is rude either.

Comment: @tunaki heck no, I fully support the site being banned on SO. The fact that it is funny is pretty much salt on a wound.

Answer (score 0):

#### Being "terse", "concise" or "succinct" is not objectively rude, abusive or offensive in and of itself.

@torazaburo has a valid point with the flowery overly polite rephrasing that turns a terse question into a passive-aggressive, condescending, patronizing *Be Nice!* nuclear bomb compared to the terse version.

The problem is *rude* is subjective, as the answers and comments prove out. Some see the examples as *rude* as you do, others see them as *not constructive*, and others see them **as they are**, just *terse* questions or statements with no reason to infer maliciousness.

*"Did you try Google?"* does not "imply"<sup>1</sup> *"You are a lazy @#$#@$@# @#$#@$@#4!!!!!*. You have to "infer"<sup>2</sup> it personally, it is just not there objectively.

[Hanlon's Razor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hanlon%27s_razor) applies to the comments in a very relevant way. Not to say that these comments or their authors are **stupid**, but to say they do not qualify for accusations of *malicious* intent.

#### To Be Clear:

> Personally I see these examples as what they are terse
> questions/statements that do not contain anything that qualifies them
> as *rude* by the guidelines or standards.
>
> I do not think they are *not constructive* as they are all probably valid questions or statements if taken in context.
>
> I would take no action on any of the examples.
>
> If it was something like the example that @torazaburo posted, that I would judge as rude, passive-aggressive, condescending and patronizing and an abuse of the intent of the *Be Nice!* policy.

<sub>1. *to indicate or suggest without being explicitly stated*</sub>

<sub>2. *deduce or conclude (information) from evidence and reasoning rather than from explicit statements.*</sub>

Answer (score -5):

Let's see how to **classify** these comments:

> - Nobody is going to do your homework for you. Go do it yourself
> - Go do your own homework

https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/140534/320339, https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/15144/320339, [Are we getting overly aggressive in comments towards homework questions (again)?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272421/)

> Your comment was not constructive. [...] If you don't like answering homework questions and think a question is homework then just don't answer.

> Just flag them for being offensive. A moderator can (and will) remove them.

## Conclusion: Not constructive, Offensive

---

> - Have you tried anything?
> - Have you even tried to solve your problem?

https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/172760/320339

> I agree - these are getting old. If the question's really missing something, either down-vote / close / flag or take the time to explain what is missing.

SE has also introduced a feature for these, *comments that consist of little more than "what have you tried" can be deleted with a single flag."*

## Conclusion: Not constructive

---

> - Did you try Google?

https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/76201/320339

> I think those should be flagged with prejudice. If the answer is on Stack Overflow already, then mark as duplicate.

## Conclusion: Not constructive

---

The problem here was the flag you raised, rude / offensive flag is evaluated differently among moderators (and goes into high priority que), the current correct flag is the "Not constructive" flag.

This is the related FAQ: [Etiquette for posting civil and informative comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/138173/etiquette-for-posting-civil-and-informative-comments).

Comment: I see that most off your answer is based off of the example comments i posted. But as I said to another answer, take them with a grain of salt. They are just examples, and there are many different ones that I would have posted if I had the time. The point I'm making is that their somewhat rude.

Comment: The first two posts linked here are very old, they may or may not still be applicable. The third link seems to over all negate your findings. The third link is quoted out of context. Shog says there that if it is applicable to the question, then it is fine. The problem they were having was repeated "what have you tried" comments on the same question, and the comments being posted where they made no sense. The last example... yeah I agree with that. If it is a duplicated question then it should be closed as such. But other than the last example, this doesn't hold water.

Comment: @Tiny please find me one meta that says any of these comments are constructive and I will agree with you, I know that the overall meta crowd thinks this is ok and you have taken the easy path, but it is actually only crap added to crap that SE would like to avoid.

Comment: I'm not disagreeing with you. I'm just pointing out that your arguments don't hold water

Comment: @Tiny hmm old meta ok (but there no other meta saying differently), cite something from 3 link that negates and show me where Shog says it ok if it is applicable to question, or is it just meta fun?

Comment: @Mr.goosberry I know [Can I have a dump of rude/abusive comments?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326494/can-i-have-a-dump-of-rude-abusive-comments), [To nuke, or not to nuke- that is the question:](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333397/to-nuke-or-not-to-nuke-that-is-the-question) however the usual meta crowd tend to blame the asker and as you see focus on the less offensive example to show you where you are wrong. The solution is to flag as **non-constructive**, these comments are additional crap that need's to be  shoveled.

Comment: @PetterFriberg I think you pinged the wrong guy. Did you mean to ping Tiny? If you did mean me then my response is: Yeah, I think that is what I'll do from now on. Flag them as not-constructive. Unless of course they are obviously rude and/or offensive.

Comment: @Mr.goosberry No I meant to ping you, showing that I know the overall problem of these comments (those are meta that I made on subject), however on meta your examples are fundamental and the least offensive comment will be used as example. I'm personally a bit tired of these comments, since I see a lot (having bot's scanning for them) and according to me there is already enough crap to shovel (questions and NAA answers).

Comment: @PetterFriberg Yes. One, of the reasons I made this post is because I keep seeing the same old comments on every new users post. We get it. The new user should do this or do that. Rudeness/Offensiveness aside, do people who post these types of comments really think that they're helping that much?

Comment: @Mr.goosberry I can't judge what people think, what I can judge is that the people that post those comment are often very hard working SO users that I admire for there commitment to SO and it's content, but this just increase my frustration : ), since not only are they generating more noise, sometimes the OP can't keep his cool and all hell breaks loose. Conclusion: more crap, more work for SO users, more work for moderators. The correct action is so simple and so fast, down vote and close vote. Note: your question never went to hot tab, you currently only have meta users ideas and votes.

Comment: @Mr.goosberry this is a blog post from one of the founders of SE [Summer of Love](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/07/the-hunting-of-the-snark/), this will give you an idea what one of the founders of SE thinks about these comments.

Comment: @PetterFriberg thanks for the link I'll check it out.

Comment: "Just to clarify: I don't begrudge comments asking for clarification or explanation when they're applicable" does that not imply that it is ok if it is applicable to question? And... the whole accepted answer and the fact that the question is very negatively scored kind of points to negating what you are attributing to it.

Comment: @TinyGiant not sure about this, this question was only visibile to meta users (hence the scoring is the view of these users) and have no official answer for either SE staff nor moderators, furthermore it is similar to this [question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333397/to-nuke-or-not-to-nuke-that-is-the-question), which had a similar negative start but with some luck hit the hot tab and got regular user traffic on it (which inverted the votes),

Comment: The idea of the question was to show this very well know problem, many answers focused on single non offensive comments, but the [intent](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334870/what-exactly-is-considered-rude-or-offensive-in-comments-anymore/334882?noredirect=1#comment397250_334882) of the question was how to handle these **non-constructive** and sometime offensive comments. Still not sure I can only direct to the current [FAQ](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/138173/etiquette-for-posting-civil-and-informative-comments) of SE, the examples there are similar.

Comment: I hope in next comments you show me some meta preferibile with moderators or SE staff answer, telling that these comments should not be flagged as non-constructive, or a meta indicating that you can be less "nice" if you judge the question is very bad.

Comment: @Mr.goosberry, a community manager just answer on this post http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/335378/5292302, "just flag it", *to be safe use non-constructive*