# Why my comments were flagged as being rude?

Tags: discussion, comments, rude-or-abusive

I waited a whole week to find this opportunity again to write on meta. I was suspended for a week, now being out of rehab. Weird moments when I saw the suspension banner but that was a good experience after all because I was being curious about it all the time.

I asked the moderators at the very first moments if they will help me to figure out the reason of the 7-day suspension period that I'm sentenced to and they gratefully pointed to some comments of mine in response and added:

> Don't insult people or make sarcastic remarks.

I read comments, I agreed with two comments of those six comments that were mentioned (as being rude / sarcastic) and asked about the other four. I didn't get any answer back (maybe it was supposed to be that way) so I'm here to do it.

1. > Is that for real?

Question: Is it sarcastic? Rude or insulting? As I remember I wrote this since the one I was talking to, made a statement that I wasn't sure about and was wondering if it is true. I was going to answer a question. So I asked them if they are sure about what they have said earlier. That's it.

If above comment makes a reason for a suspension (sarcastic? I don't know), so don't the following:

[image]

or

[image]

Do *Please* and *Thank you!* justify the preceding or following coming words? If yes what's wrong with *Welcome to Stack Overflow!*:

2. > Welcome to Stack Overflow! You're [forming that big part of the time we spend here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jfpCK.png).

This comment with a link to a picture would be the same as *SO is not a coding service* / *You have put no efforts* / *We don't do homeworks* / [*This is not a homework completion service*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50520409/html-get-request-and-response#comment88053304_50520409) or [*Nobody is going to do your homework for you. Go do it yourself*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334870/1020526) with less wording and more visualizing the matter. So is it rude or sarcastic?

> [None of those comments rises to the level of rudeness that warrants flagging as "rude or abusive."](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/334872/1020526)

### Comments with upvotes

If a comment received some upvotes (which means it is helpful) and flagged as being rude at the same time which one has priority over the other?

[image]

FYI, my flag on above comment was *declined* and I'm afraid if I might / could continue commenting like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50280828/regex-for-substring-and-not-substring#comment87578172_50280828):

[image]

Thank you for reading. So I have two questions: Why my comments were flagged as being rude? and why they were being accepted?

Comment: I get the feeling a lot of context is being missed here. Those comments from Hans Passant were on meta and probably directed at an experienced user. Are you saying you got suspended for posting "Is that for real?" on a meta post?

Comment: Thank you. I didn't blur the commentator for no reason. And that's my point. [Does reputation or up-votes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2645/show-all-of-my-question-answers-to-me-even-if-they-are-deleted/53297#53297) justify words being used and intention of a comment?

Comment: "Having chops" is a compliment in the English language, indicates acknowledgement of possessing great skill.  [This question about it](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/to-have-the-chops.815961/) isn't very good, you could ask at english.stackexchange.com.

Comment: I shouldn't discuss an old topic here that's the reason I didn't mention any body. Remember the comment after you.

Comment: Without full context, 2 looks sarcastic. You certainly don't welcome the user by providing the image behind a link, so you better drop the "Welcome" part... Leaving the image part. Well, that's unnecessarily too graphic than a text "SO is not a coding service". Removing that leaves with... no comment. Yeah, looks like it's better not to comment in this case. It's the same as "welcome to this site, our unwelcomed user!"

Comment: If you actually want to have a constructive discussion about this, consider: (1) Giving context its due importance -- your explanation of the circumstances of your #1 comment is too vague, and I'd say your use of that specific passage of the "[php] chops" comment qualifies as a misquote; (2) Focusing more on your own comments rather than on finding comments by others that would supposedly excuse them; and (3) Anonymising screencaps properly, if you actually care about making them anonymous.

Comment: @AndrewT. *2 looks sarcastic* I doubt did you ping *[None of those comments rises](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/334872/1020526)...* topic? Certainly much more better than *Go do it yourself*.

Comment: @revo eh, Be Nice states "*Name-calling. Focus on the post, not the person.*" while your comment casually name-called the OP, "***You're** forming that big part of the time we spend here.*". I believe you wouldn't get more trouble due to rude behavior if you instead stated "Welcome to Stack Overflow. Unfortunately, SO is not a coding service."

Comment: @duplode Well, for a comparison I needed more comments. So addressing those two is valid in this context. *Anonymising screencaps properly* I did but a curious person doesn't bother to [google the parts](https://www.google.com/search?q="please+learn+how+to+use+and+moderate+meta").

Comment: @AndrewT. So do you mean *You have put no efforts* means name calling? or ***Your question** is forming that big part of the time we spend here* is fine?

Answer (score 17):

> Question: Is it sarcastic? Rude or insulting?

You didn't provide the context for the comment (if someone posted a link to questionable and/or surprising documentation, I could see that response being OK), but absent context, I would certainly say "yes".

> Do Please and Thank you! justify the preceding or following coming words?

No. But those statements you cited aren't rude, insulting, or sarcastic. They're to the point.

Even if we pretend that "is that for real" is not rude or insulting, the fact is that it contributes *nothing* to the comment (again, absent context). It doesn't inform the reader of what they did wrong. It doesn't help them at all.

By contrast, telling the reader how audits work... tells them how audits work. That's genuinely useful information, as is the fact that experience/skills in a tag doesn't change how audits work. The "please learn how to use and moderate meta" is less useful, but it is presumably a preamble to the actually useful information on what the user did wrong.

> This comment with a link to a picture would be the same as SO is not a coding service / You have put no efforts / We don't do homeworks / This is not a homework completion service or Nobody is going to do your homework for you. Go do it yourself with less wording and more visualizing the matter. So is it rude or sarcastic?

Yes. Clearly. It's a sarcastic insult of the person.

You're not trying to inform them of something in a direct manor. You could do that easily enough with text. But by using an image and a sarcastic remark about their place in that image, you're clearly insulting the user. And you're making them go to an image for the privilege of even understanding the insult.

That's not nice.

Being nice is not just about what you say; it's about how you say it. If you had just said, "we're not a code-writing service", that would be OK. But the way you said it indicated clear contempt with the user personally.

It would be better to just downvote, close where appropriate, and move on.

> If a comment received some upvotes (which means it is helpful) and flagged as being rude at the same time which one has priority over the other?

Rude always has priority. A bunch of people can agree with an insulting comment, but that doesn't mean the comment isn't insulting. You can't shield yourself behind other people's agreement.

Comment: *the fact is that it contributes nothing to the comment...* it doesn't mean it should be flagged as being rude either. I think only moderators are qualified to answer those two questions being asked. Comments on other parts of question are welcome.

Comment: @revo: "*it doesn't mean it should be flagged as being rude either.*" I was pointing out a big difference between your comments and the redacted person. I wasn't saying that your comment wasn't rude; my point is that your comments clearly weren't about providing information, while the other person's were. "*I think only moderators are qualified to answer those two questions being asked.*" Community moderators are supposed to enforce the standards set down by the community.

Comment: The final point in your comment should be included in your answer as it is key.